# How do I run Django and PHP together on one Apache server?

Tags: php, django, apache-config

I can currently run either Django through mod_wsgi or PHP on my Apache server.

My Django projects run at: http://localhost and source is at C:/django_proj

My PHP projects run at: http://php.localhost and source is at C:/web

If I turn both on, php.localhost and localhost go to the Django project. I've already set them up through Apache virtual hosts.

Here are some relevant lines in httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/web"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/django_proj">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Include "C:/django_proj/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf"
```

The relevant lines in `apache_django_wsgi.conf` is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/django_proj/apache/proj.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/django_proj/apache">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Inside httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<Directory C:/web>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory C:/django_proj>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/django_proj"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/web"
    ServerName php.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

My PHP project is current inaccessible.  Does anyone have any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I run dozens of mod_wsgi/Django sites, PHP sites, and a Rails site with a single Apache.

It's mostly done using virtual hosts but I have some that are running both on the same domain.

You just need to put your `WSGIScriptAlias /...` after any other Location/Alias directives.

Lets say, for example, I want to run phpMyAdmin on the same domain as a Django site.  The config would look something like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /full/path/to/phpmyadmin/
<Directory /full/path/to/phpmyadmin>
   Options -Indexes
   ...etc...
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /full/path/to/django/project/app.wsgi
<Directory /full/path/to/django/project>
    Options +ExecCGI
    ...etc...
</Directory>
```

**Edit**:

Your configuration should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/django_proj"
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/django_proj/apache/proj.wsgi"
    <Directory "C:/django_proj/apache">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/web"
    ServerName php.localhost
    Alias / C:/web
    <Directory C:/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't need those `<Directory>` directives in `http.conf`... do all your configuration in the Virtual hosts.

Also, completely get rid of the `<Directory />` block.

Comment: That's good to know, but I want to point my Django project to ,y main domain while my PHP project to a sub-domain, for instance:
http://localhost      -->  My Django Proj
http://php.localhost  -->  My PHP Proj
Do you know how I can achieve the above, I already have the above running as virtual hosts.

Comment: You need to put your <Alias> and <Directory> directives inside the appropriate <VirtualHost> blocks.  In other words, put the WSGIScriptAlias inside the block where ServerName is localhost.  I'll make it more clear by editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working. I removed the "Alias / C:/web" and it works fine now.  I also took out the Directory blocks from httpd.conf.

Comment: in django VH part `DocumentRoot "C:/django_proj"` is needed? i think this line raising security problems...?

Comment: @VanGale This is a great answer; can you explain as to why a VHOST is better than an Alias? Or perhaps what is the real difference between the two? Thanks.

Comment: You are a genius. It worked like a charm I just had to put Alias path.I was searching for this everywhere in the internet for 2 hours.

Answer (score 8):

Your `WSGIScriptAlias / ...` directive is telling Apache that everything request starting with "/" should get fed through Django's WSGI handler.  If you changed that to read `WSGIScriptAlias /django-proj/ ...` instead, only requests starting with "/django-proj" would get passed into Django.

An alternative would be to start setting up virtual hosts for each project.  This way you could configure Apache to put each project at the / of it's own domain, and you wouldn't need to worry about the configuration for one project affecting one of your other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try removing this block `<Directory />` in httpd-conf.

Include httpd-vhost.conf and and try puting my `WSGIScriptAlias / "/somewhere/file.wsgi"` in virtual host section of httpd-vhosts which listens to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that if you are using Apache *ProxyPass*, it's possible to deny certain URL patterns so that it falls to mod_php.

```
ProxyPass /wordpress !
<Location /wordpress>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```