# Apache config for PHP and Django

Tags: php, django, apache

I'm wanting to run PHP and Django together on the same apache config and I'm wondering how to do that?

```
devserver.com <- Serving PHP files from /var/www
devserver.com/django <- Serving Django from /var/www/django (/var/www/django/mod.wsgi)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I run Django and PHP together on one Apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020390/how-do-i-run-django-and-php-together-on-one-apache-server)