# Can I host a facebook PHP application in my Django site?

Tags: php, django, facebook

I've got a website http://www.mydomain.com made with Django, and I'd like to use the domain to host a facebook application written in PHP, in something like http://www.mydomain.com/facebook/myapp/.
Is that possible? How can I do that?

Thanks

Jul

Comment: This should be an Apache/nginx/lighttpd question and you should post it on serverfault.com
In a nutshell, tweak your http server settings with Directory, AddHandler, rewrites etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you should configure your server so that documents for that specific URL will be parsed by PHP instead of django. This configuration depends on the server you're using. You can find more information for apache [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020390/how-do-i-run-django-and-php-together-on-one-apache-server).