# How to force django and php to work together?

Tags: django

I have project in django on my server (wsgi, configured in apache)

I do not have access to config file, i have only django.wsgi file in my public_html folder.

And django works fine, but i wish in one of the public_html subdirectory place php script.

How to do it?

Comment: since python will use the wsgi protocole, maybe you could use another protocole to use php, for example cgi?

Comment: @abdel - correct, use whatever plugin is normally used for php as the server will see the .php and run based on that. Make your comment an answer and get up votes :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020390/how-do-i-run-django-and-php-together-on-one-apache-server and http://www.scottgorlin.com/2009/07/embedding-django-in-php/ i think this can help?

Comment: I don't have access to virtual host file, only .htaccess (simple, only rewriterules)

Comment: am sorry, am not a php dev, but i've found this, and maybe this can help:
"..Changes made to an existing .htaccess file will be seen immediately. When creating new .htaccess files or deleting existing .htaccess files, you might not see changes for up to an hour.."
[the original link](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1082) maybe other one can provide better answer, sorry again :)

Answer (score 2):

since python will use the **wsgi** protocol, maybe you could use another protocol to use php, for example **cgi** ;) (thank you Kevin)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got access to config, the someone must have added:

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
```

to the main Apache config or you added it to your .htaccess file for your Django application to work.

All that is required is the appropriate AddHandler directive for .php extension files and PHP code should be able to be placed in the same directories without interference presuming Apache as a whole has PHP support enabled.