# Issue when setting-up wsgi as an alias path in apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualhost

NOTE: This question is different from '[Add a prefix to all Flask routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes)' as I am trying to resolve this at apache level. Additional, the suggested fix for flask routes did not work!

Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020696/2761030), I'm trying to set up apache to serve PHP files by default, but point a given alias (i.e. `/flaskapp`) to a wsgi path. The wsgi file in turn routes requests to a python flask app.

Here's the apache config that I'm trying (under `000-default.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        Alias / /var/www/html/
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias /flaskapp "/var/www/flaskapp/deploy.wsgi"
        <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
                 Options +ExecCGI
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After doing a `service apache2 restart` I find that requests to `http://myip/flaskapp` result in a 404 error. Everything else works fine.

Things I've tried so far:

- Double checking all the file and folder paths (no issues found)
- Using the wsgi part of the above code to set up the wsgi app as a standalone virtualhost (works fine)
- Adding `app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/flaskapp'` to my app.py file, as suggested the question '[Add a prefix to all Flask routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes)' (Didn't have any effect)

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Don't use Alias /. That overrides mod_wsgi completely. Use DocumentRoot directive to specify where primary site files are located. That way mod_wsgi can override for a sub URL.

Comment: And yes you are correct, not same question as claimed duplicate. People here on SO usually don't understand subtleties though and just make assumptions.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton - adding DocumentRoot resolved the issue. Feel free to write this up as an answer, or I can do so this evening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    Alias / /var/www/html/
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

use:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Using '/' with `Alias` takes precedence over everything else including mod_wsgi's ability to intercept requests at a sub URL. So for stuff at root of the site you need to use `DocumentRoot` directive.