# How do i run php and django on same server and domain

Tags: php

I am trying to run php and django on same apache server

I followed this link
    [How do I run Django and PHP together on one Apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020390/how-do-i-run-django-and-php-together-on-one-apache-server)

`httdp.vhost.conf` file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
    DocumentRoot "D:/django/django-env/myproject"
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/django/django-env/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "D:/django/django-env/myproject/myproject">
       Require all granted

    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/paperclip"
    ServerName php.localhost
    Alias / C:/xampp/htdocs/paperclip
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/paperclip>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What i am doing wrong? The Django project works fine but the PHP code is not running.
I get: `404 found error`

Comment: I don't think you can run them both on the same port `*:80`

Comment: i followed many links thats say it is possible